# Solve $\lim\limits_{z\to 2i} 2x + y^2 = 4$ using the formal definition of limit

Tags: limits, complex-numbers, epsilon-delta

First of all we need to remember that $z=x+iy$. Well, I'm confusing about a tip from the author where he says to consider $|z-z_{0}| < 1$. Then we need to prove $|x| < 1$ and $|y|<3$ . This is the part I'm not understanding! How can I prove that? Then he says to use this affirmation to conclude:

$$\begin{align}|f(z) - f(z_0)| &= |2x+y^2 - 4| \\&= |2x + (y-2)(y+2)| \\&\leq 2|x| + |y-2|(|y|+2)\\& \leq 5|x| + 5|y-2|\end{align}$$
and then $5|x| + 5|y-2| \leq 10|z-2i|$

Comment: Use \lim, not \limits, I think.

Answer (score 1):

$|a+ib|=\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}}$ if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Hence $|a+ib| \geq \sqrt {a^{2}}=|a|$ and $|a+ib| \geq \sqrt {b^{2}}=|b|$. Thus $|(x+iy)- (0+2i)| =|x+i(y-2)| <1$ implies that $|x| <1$ and $|y-2| <1$ so $|y| <1+2=3$.

[To finish the proof take $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {10}$]

Comment: Man, thank you! I've been studying for 8h and this is so obvious but I couldn't see this because I'm very tired. I know that it was a foolish question but thank you for the help.

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro MSE policy says that it is polite to accept the useful answer.